# javafx.fxml.LoadException programming at javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I am working on a javaFX Program (built with scenebuilder) and have some huge problems, due to being new to javafx.

I have a Main Window with a Menubar. At this Menubar I can select "NewSystems" to add new Systems. Selecting that, a new window (separate fxml file with separate Controller) appears with a few Textfields and Textareas, as well as some buttons.

The way I want it to go is like this:
User enters Name, ID, etc., in the specific Textfields. Then by clicking the Button "Add" I want to save every Textfield in a different String.

This is the mainController. Clicking on "NewSystems" uses the handleNewSystem method below. The Window is opening just fine.

```
       package application;
       import java.io.IOException;

       import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
       import javafx.stage.Modality;
       import javafx.stage.Stage;
       import javafx.scene.Parent;
       import javafx.scene.Scene;
       import javafx.fxml.FXML;
       import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;


       public class MainWindowController {
       @FXML
       private void handleNewSystem(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
       FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new 
       FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("/application/SystemData.fxml"));
       Parent root = fxmlLoader.load();
       Stage stage = new Stage();
       stage.initModality(Modality.APPLICATION_MODAL);
       stage.setOpacity(1);
       stage.setTitle("New System");
       stage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 600));
       stage.showAndWait();
          }

       }
```

The SystemDataController:

```
@FXML
public AnchorPane SystemData;
public TextField ID;
public TextField SysName;
public TextField SysCustomer;
public TextField SysProjectlabel;
public TextArea SysDescription;
public TextArea SysComment;
public TextField SysTechnology;
public Button addSystem;


@FXML
private void handleAddSystem(ActionEvent event) throws IOException {
   String string = ID.getText();
   System.out.println(string);
  }
```

With the line:

```
 <TextField fx:id="ID" onAction="#handleAddSystem" 
   GridPane.columnIndex="1"/>
```

I manage to Print out what's written in the ID Textfield without problems.

Now i tried to get all the textfield values when the button "add" is pressed. Therefore I removed the "onAction="#handleAddSystem" on above code and added it to the button:

```
 <Button fx:id="addSystem" onAction="#handleAddSystem"  layoutX="14.0" 
 layoutY="561.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleAddSystem" 
 prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="52.0" text="Add " />
```

Which causes a lot of errors I can't solve. Not even the window that contains the button and textfields (clicking on "NewSystem" at the main window usually opened it)

I got following error codes:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: 
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/UserName/git/Team/GUI/bin/application/SystemData.fxml:63
```

Line 63 in SystemData.fxml is the one I posted above:

```
 <Button fx:id="addSystem" onAction="#handleAddSystem"  layoutX="14.0" 
 layoutY="561.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#handleAddSystem" 
 prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="52.0" text="Add " />
```

I'm looking forward to your help and sorry if the question got to long.

The complete stack Trace:

```
 Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" 
 java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.
handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent
 (CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent
 (EventHandlerManager.java:238)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent
(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
 at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent
(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent
(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.control.MenuItem.fire(MenuItem.java:462)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer
.doSelect(ContextMenuContent.java:1405)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ContextMenuContent$MenuItemContainer
.lambda$createChildren$343(ContextMenuContent.java:1358)
  
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord
.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent
(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent
(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent
(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent
(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent
(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent
(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent
(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent
(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent
(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent
(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent
(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent
(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)

at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.
run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:381)
at 
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification
.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at 
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$354
(GlassViewEventHandler.java:417)
at 
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock
(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
at 
com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassView
EventHandler.java:416)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at 
com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
... 43 more
Caused by: javafx.fxml.LoadException: 
/C:/Users/Mahir/git/Team23/GUI/bin/application/SystemData.fxml:63

at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.constructLoadException(FXMLLoader.java:2601)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2543)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:2409)
at 
application.MainWindowController.handleNewSystem
(MainWindowController.java:17)
... 53 more

Caused by: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:
[63,194]
Message: http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-xml-names-
19990114#AttributeNotUnique?Button&onAction
at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLStreamReaderImpl.next(Unknown 
Source)
at javax.xml.stream.util.StreamReaderDelegate.next(Unknown Source)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2513)
... 56 more
```

Comment: Please post the complete stack trace.

Comment: It looks like you have `onAction` twice in your `<Button>` component. No idea if that would cause such an error.

Comment: Hypnic Jerk..... lol... thats it. And i was searching hours for solutions.. Thank you!